# unique_ptr вызывает деструктор только при reset

Tags: c++, указатели, c++17

Почему `std::unique_ptr<...>` вызывает деструктор целевого объекта только если вызвать

```
std::unique_ptr<>::reset(nullptr);
```

При этом, если вызвать `std::unique_ptr<>::release`, то ничего не происходит, но указатель обнуляется.

Что делать необходимо дабы не происходило таких ситуаций?

Comment: В первую очередь ответить на вопрос: а с чего вы вообще взялись вызывать эти функции? И если вам децствительно нужно что-то вызывать, то вызывайте правильную функыию. Никто кроме вас не знает, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @AnT: метод `release` подразумевает под собой несколько понятий, освободить объект, память, или указатель, поэтому происходят иногда такие ситуации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При вызове `std::unique_ptr::release` владение указателем передается вызывающему коду. Игнорирование возвращаемого значения является ошибкой. Что делать? Ничего. Не надо вызывать `release` если нет намерения вручную удалить объект.

Comment: Это новвоведение стандарта, при использовании `14`, `11` такого я не наблюдал?

Comment: @LLENN Это всегда так было.

Comment: А как тогда явным образом можно уничтожить объект, заранее зная когда его необходимо уничтожить?

Comment: @LLENN Можно вызвать `p.reset();` или `p = nullptr;` или даже короче `p = {};`.

Comment: Отлично, намотаю на ус :)

Comment: Немного не по теме, но можно узнать сколько вы с данным языком работаете?

Comment: @LLENN Ну профессионально C++ использую уже лет 9